# Nant script - How to check if it runs on a server or on a dev machine?

Tags: nant

I have a `Nant build` script.
It may be executed on either dev machine or build server.

I want to skip a build step on a dev machine but still run it on a server.

How can I check if the script runs on a server or on a dev machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about adding something special to the build server. I can think of two options from the top of my head:

- Environment variable: just make sure build server has a specific environment variable and [check its existence in your NAnt script](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/functions/environment.get-variable.html)
- Special environment.include file: make sure build server has a special environment.include file in the root of the C drive, for example, and define build server specific NAnt properties there, like `<property name="is.build.server" value="true" />`.

  You can include this kind of file like this:

  `<include buildfile="\Environment.include" if="${file::exists('\Environment.include')}"/>`